# How to add a new mime-type to the 'file' command

Tags: terminal, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mavericks, epub

I use the following command to create a list of files and their mime-type's, to be used in a script to generate a content.opf file for an epub (OSX 10.6.8).

```
find * -type f -exec file {} --mime-type \;
```

The result is as follows:

```
...
OEBPS/cover.xhtml: application/xml
OEBPS/css/style.css: text/x-c
OEBPS/img/cover.png: image/png
...
```

The second item is not what I expected: it should list as:

```
OEBPS/css/style.css: text/css
```

The file man page says the value is read from definitions in /usr/share/file/magic and indeed there is no css definition there. Does anyone know how I can add one myself? I cannot find a manual to write these.

Before this approach I used a grep pattern to write the mime type, but I thought this would be a 'nicer' way of doing things...

Comment: This is ultimately not going to be a fruitful way to do it, because you don't actually want 'application/xml' as the mime-type for the content documents. The spec wants 'application/xhtml+xml': http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section2.3

Comment: @Liza: you are absolutely right. I thought this would be a more graceful way to solve this, but I will stick with my regex based solution: it works in it present state.